# How do we interpret disconnected diagrams in scattering theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, s-matrix-theory, scattering-cross-section

It is apparent that disconnected diagram contributes additional delta functions to the corresponding matrix element. For example, we consider the scalar $\phi^3$ theory and the following $2\rightarrow4$ scattering process：

$$\mathcal{L}=-{1\over2}\phi(\square+m^2)\phi+{g\over 3!}\phi^3$$

[image]

This process seems physically trivial because it can be separated. However, if we consider it under the standard framework, we'll run into a mathematical glitch. The matrix element for this process is:

$$\mathrm{i}\mathcal{M}=(\mathrm{i}g)^2(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_3+p_4-p_1)$$

which results in a divergent contribution to the cross section:

$$\mathrm{d}\sigma={1\over|v_1-v_2|}{g^4(2\pi)^4\delta^4(p_3+p_4-p_1)TV\over2E_1\ 2E_2}\mathrm{d}\Pi_{LPS}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\delta^4(0)={TV\over(2\pi)^4})$$

How do we interpret this seemingly unphysical result?

Comment: It is ok for the differential cross-section $\frac{\text d\sigma}{\text d\Pi_{\rm{LPS}}}$ to have singularities, as long as we can make sense of its integral over any region of Lorentzian phase space.

Comment: How is your question related to disconnected diagrams? Can you just take a simple connected diagram of a particle decay and make the same argument about $\delta^{(4)}(0)$ appearing? How would you deal with it in that case?

Comment: @SolubleFish However the singularity here isn't one delta function but the square of a delta function, which can't be integrated out.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov In case of connected diagram, there is indeed a $\delta^{(4)}(0)$ for overall momentum conservation as well. But it can be absorbed by the periodic boundary normalization. This is already taken care of in the example above. For details you can see Weinberg or Schwartz's relevant chapters. However, for disconnected diagram there is an additional $\delta^{(4)}(0)$ which can't be absorbed and normalized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've recently discovered that the extra delta function for the amplitude is exactly what is needed for cluster decomposition principle. I'm too lazy to write details here.